# Domain-Driven Design shared Entity

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, entity-relationship, bounded-contexts

I'm just starting my professional journey with **Domain-Driven Design**. I have a problem with the model of my classes. Below is a simplified class diagram.

[image]

I have two bounded contexts: **Population** and **Issues**.

`Person` is created with at least one document. `Person` can report a new `Issue` attaching multiple `IssueAttachment`.

I want to centralize files storage as a single `File` entity that I will persist in the single database table. The reason for centralization is the implementation of common actions before persistence, such as data compression or obtaining md5 hash. Also, storing all files in a single table simplifies testing data dumping process as I have to ignore just a single table to exclude heavy blobs.

However, after reading many articles, I can conclude that sharing entities between various contexts is not recommended.

Could you give me some design advice on how to deal with such a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have already identified the two bounded context its great. Refer to following figure to understand from top view.
[image]

Now if we look each of these bounded context. In this case taking an example of onion architecture as you can see in figure2. (You can choose any architecture which fits your need).
[image]

Yes, you have heard right. Its indeed true the models in two different bounded context is different. For the moment you may see same class with same properties.
But since they are in different bounded context they carry different meaning for the business. May be give it a shot to think in the following described way once you fill the gap between your infra to domain. Possibly you will see different meaning.

However in your case, your concern with sharing the same infra(ex: Filesystem) can be handled at the outer most layer of bounded context without worrying or mixing with your domain business.

As seen from figure-2 use the infra-layer which is in the outer most layer of the shell to interact with shared infra (Ex: Filesystem). Now in the domain (population or issue context respectively) define an interface which defines the respective business need. Which you can implement in application layer, from where you can interact with your infra-layer (of same bounded context). In turn you will be able to communicate with shared infrastructure (filesystem).

It does not matter tomorrow which infra you are going to use and what ever changes in the infra your domain business remains intact of it. So in this way you can keep things isolated. And in infra-layer with very less change and having some sort of mapper or adapter you will be able make the magical interaction with shared-infrastructure (filesystem).

Let me know your thought.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive response, I appreciate it.
As comments in StackOverflow have restricted length, I'll divide my answer in two. I got your point about shared infrastructure. However, I still have some doubts. As I haven't done more significant projects using true DDD, it's sometimes hard for me to understand how building blocks interact together. In the infra layer, I'm planning to use MySQL as file storage. So each File will be conveniently identified by UUID.

Comment: `Person` creates a new issue, and as a request's DTO, I'll get data related to Issue itself and an array of Files. I'll pass it to ReportNewIssueUseCase, where I'll implement interaction between domain models and persisting data through repositories. Based on that step, I doubt how this use case will persist files and relate them with the Issue? I believe that I should surely create FileRepository for data persistence. From the definition, Repositories persist and retrieve domain entities, as File is not a domain entity, then how to interact with Repository to store File in the database table?

Comment: I think, i can see what you are trying to say.
Don't see file as file(image/pdf), but try to discover what that file is for your business.
Let the file be in any form it does not matter.

1. what matters is "what it represents in the business". 
   Try calling it like supporting-document (coining some business word, but you know better).

2. Lets say its some metadata and does not make any sense to business still you need to store something.
   Its ok to pass around DTO i think, its not mandatory to pass domain always. But try as much as possible to communicate using domain models.